# Rendering path with Meteor Iron Router

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, iron-router

I'm implementing [cast.js](https://github.com/bmcmahen/cast) in Meteor and I'm trying to render a larger photo after clicking on a thumbnail using Iron Router, however I'm having trouble rendering the correct path. The thumbnails render just fine, however when the photo is clicked I'm getting an error of `No route found for path:`.

The template that I'm using to render each thumbnail photo is

```
  var renderTemplate = function(obj){
   return "<a href='{{pathFor photo}}'><img class='img-rounded' src='" + obj.picture + "'></a>"
  };

  Template.userPhotos.rendered = function(){
    var el = this.find('#cast');
    var mycast = cast(el);
    mycast.draw(renderTemplate);

    this.handle = Meteor.autorun(function(){
      var picture = Photos.find().fetch();
      mycast
        .data(picture , '_id')
        .dynamic(150, 150, 10, 10);
    });
  }
```

And is placed within the `cast` id in this template

```
<template name="userPhotos">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="photos">
      <div id='cast'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is coming from the href that is rendered. I'm trying to pass the photo `_id` and render a larger photo in the below template, which is called "source" in mongoDB.

```
<template name="photo">
  <div class="well">
    <img class="img-rounded" src="{{source}}">
  </div>
</template>
```

Currently, my router is set up as follows:

```
this.route('photo', {
    path: '/photo/:_id', 
    waitOn: function() {
      return [
        Meteor.subscribe('picture', this.params._id),
      ];
    },
    data: function() { return Photos.findOne(this.params._id); }
  });
```

Once a photo is clicked, it sends me to this path and throws this error `Oh no! No route found for path: "/%7B%7BpathFor"`. %7B is URL speak for `{` so it looks like handlebars or Iron Router isn't translating the template when it is passed through as a string.

Any thoughts on how to improve this code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `renderTemplate` function is just returning a string, not a rendered template. Rewrite the template you were trying to assemble there as a Handlebars template using helpers:

```
<template name="photoLink">
  <a href="{{getPathForPhoto}}">
    <img class="img-rounded" src="{{getThumbnailSrc}}">
  </a>
</template>
```

and (you'll have to adapt the below because I don't know what the `this` variables in your context have as properties; basically, get the path (or the components of the path, like the _id) and the thumbnail path/src into this function via `this` or via a passed parameter):

```
Template.photoLink.getPathForPhoto = function() {
  return "/photo/" + this._id;
}

Template.photoLink.getThumbnailSrc = function() {
  return "/thumbnail/" + this._id;
}
```

Again you'll need to rework the above functions to get them to work for your app; and you'll need to create a route for the thumbnail paths too.

Is it annoying to create tiny JavaScript functions for every little thing that requires the slightest bit of logic in Handlebars? Yes. But that's just the way it's designed, sorry. You could use other functions to render the template from your assembled string, but this capability is going away in the next version of Meteor.

Comment: I did have that type of set up implemented into my app and it worked great. Problem is that I'm trying to install [cast.js](https://github.com/bmcmahen/cast) into my app. The instructions on meteor usage renders a string template. Is there a better way to do this within this example since to my knowledge it looks like the HTML string need to be rendered in `<div id='cast'></div>`?

Comment: Ah, that's a whole additional thing. Cast is using jQuery to insert its content inside `<div id='cast'>`, and the `renderTemplate` there is creating HTML that jQuery then adds to your page. It's happening outside of Meteor and its Handlebars rendering. See https://github.com/bmcmahen/cast#meteor-usage; specifically the `rendered` function is where all that magic is happening. It's a bit redundant (first Meteor renders a template, then jQuery adds all these additional ones) but simpler than rebuilding cast.js on your own within Meteor/Handlebars. See cast's Meteor example.

Comment: Interesting, this is starting to make a bit more sense to me :) Yes I've been following the instructions, however I'm still having a bit of trouble with it. I added more information to my question that might be able to help. Basically the string renders fine, however there href looks like it is pulling exactly what is in the `' '` instead of the handlebars template.